# react ag-grid server side Infinite Row Model Is it possible to make a graphql

Tags: reactjs, graphql

react ag-grid server side Infinite Row Model Is it possible to make a graphql?
react ag-grid server side Infinite Row Model Is it possible to make a graphql?
react ag-grid server side Infinite Row Model Is it possible to make a graphql?

```
  const {data:LOAD_SHOP_DATA,refetch:SHOP_REFETCH,error:shopErr} = useQuery(GET_SHOP, { variables: { param:{}, ver }});
const onGridReady = (params) => {
  SET_GRID_API(params.api);
  SET_GRID_COLUMN_API(params.columnApi);

  const httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  const updateData = (data) => {
console.log(data)
    var dataSource = {
      rowCount: null,
      getRows: function (params) {
        console.log('asking for ' + params.startRow + ' to ' + params.endRow);
        setTimeout(function () {
          var rowsThisPage = data?.slice(params.startRow, params.endRow);
          var lastRow = -1;
          if (data?.length <= params.endRow) {
            lastRow = data?.length;
          }
          params.successCallback(rowsThisPage, lastRow);
        }, 500);
      },
    };
    params.api.setDatasource(dataSource);
  };
  // updateData(!LOAD_SHOP_DATA? LOAD_SHOP_DATA?.getShop);
  httpRequest.open(
    'GET',
      'http://api.pds.com:3000/api/v1/graphql/getShop'
    
  );
 
  httpRequest.send();
  httpRequest.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (httpRequest.readyState === 4 && httpRequest.status === 200) {
      console.log(JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText))
      updateData(JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText));
     
    }
  };
};
```